# libSDL2_gfx-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, sdl, linker-errors, ld

Creating an SDL2 application on Ubuntu 20.04 which uses the visual shape overlays provided by SDL2_gfx. Have both SDL2 and SDL2_gfx installed, I believe properly (`./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`... all successful), compilation is success, but program execution is not.

Error message:

```
libSDL2_gfx-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Useful commands/results/information: **

```
user@debian$ pkg-config --cflags sdl2 
-D_reentrant -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 

user@debian$ pkg-config --cflags SDL2_gfx
-D_reentrant -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 

user@debian$ pkg-config --libs sdl2 
-L/usr/local/lib -Wl, -rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl, --enable-new-dtags -lSDL2 

user@debian$ pkg-config --libs SDL2_gfx  
-L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2_gfx -Wl, -rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl, --enable-new-dtags -lSDL2 

Compile argument: gcc sdlTest.c -o sdlTesting -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 
 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -lSDL2_gfx
```

Also the compile argument:

```
gcc sdlTest.c -o sdlTesting -lSDL2 -lSDL2_gfx
```

...somehow works as well for compilation. Build error remains the same:

[image: Linux environment w/ compilation and execution]

Tried the standard compilation using linker commands `-lSDL2 -lSDL2_gfx`, expected to have a normal execution using `./sdlTesting`

Comment: Does kicking `ld` again with a `sudo ldconfig` change anything?  Also, double check your `ld` install has config files pointing at `/usr/local`.

Comment: This error has been resolved, issue was that libSDL2_gfx-1.0 had not been installed, but additional errors have now persisted. Solution was sudo apt-get install libSDL2_gfx-1.0